# Android http request readline

Tags: java, android, httprequest, bufferedreader, readline

I was trying to readline through http request of the source code of the web page.
My purpose was to read an integer value (price) from the result.

I'm using bufferedReader to readline. I had no clear idea on which method could store the data I wanted.

Below is the code I used:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8") );
String data = null;
String webPage = "";
while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
   webPage += data + "\n";
}
```

UPDATED:
this is the example result of the http request:

```
 more...<div class="price-block--grid">
                <div class="old-price-wrap">
                    <!-- begin old price -->
                    <div class="product-card__old-price">RM 1,500.00</div>
                    <!-- end old price -->
                    <!-- begin sale -->
                    <div class="product-card__sale">- 6%</div>
                    <!-- end sale -->
                </div>
                <div class="product-card__price">RM 1,408.00</div>....more
```

I was wondering is there any way for me to retrieve and store only the price value (i.e. 1408 in example) to my data variable?

Comment: Your story is not complete. Please continue. Finish with a question.

Comment: data will be stored in webPage variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default method to parse all the html and extract the needed portion. You can save all html in webPage as String and then parse the string to get price out by using code like this:

```
String toFind = "product-card__price\">";
String str1 = webPage.substring(webPage.indexOf(toFind) + toFind.length());
String priceString = str1.substring(0, str1.indexOf("<"));
int price = Integer.parseInt(priceString.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have multiple divs in the html that you want to parse and save than you have to run a loop and parse it depending on your needs, for example:

```
String to = "product-card__price\">";
String remainingText = webPage;
ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
while (remainingText.indexOf(to) >= 0) {
    String tokenString = remainingText.substring(remainingText.indexOf(to) + to.length());
    String priceString = tokenString.substring(0, tokenString.indexOf("<"));
    int price = Integer.parseInt(priceString.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    integers.add(price);
    remainingText = tokenString;
}
```

Comment: sorry,i've updated the output of the httpRequest,the output of the httpRequest will not always be integer.Any idea?

Comment: I have updated my answer, check now! You can parse the response and get price out like this!!

Comment: Hi Asif Mujteba,thanks.This does solve my prob,but i had to store more than 1 price .hence i had to do another loop after str1 in order to save all the price right?

Comment: Thanks!! this really helps a lot. Sorry for such long question as i'm still a beginner in Android Programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure every line is only integer than just create an integer variable or array (if you have multiple lines) and parse the string to integer: `Integer.parseInt(data);` If you have other characters in variable data that are not numbers you can use regex to delete none digits:

```
data = data.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sorry,i've updated the httpRequest above.The everyline will Not only consists of integer but other character and symbol.Any idea?